# How to find the IP of a CSGO comunity server?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I was playing a retake server in *Counter Strike: Global Offensive*. Then my friend say give him the server IP address so that he can join and play with me. The question is how can I find the IP server and let him know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The step is very simple.

1. Open the console table and type `status`

   [image]
2. After you enter `status`, it will pop out a lot info and there you can find the server IP address. Below the picture, I have underline with red color and that's the current server IP address you playing at.

   [image]

After that, you can just copy it and send it to your friend.