# Unable to get the server IP address via CS:GO "status" command in linux

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, linux

I got this after running the `status` command in the CS:GO console:

```
] status
Connected to =[A:1:176517124:15634]:0
hostname: Valve CS:GO EU West Server (srcds006.131.40)
version : 1.37.6.8 secure
os      :  Linux
type    :  official dedicated
map     : cs_office
players : 8 humans, 5 bots (16/0 max) (not hibernating)
```

What does `[A:1:176517124:15634]:0` mean?

I guessed it could be in fact something like this(these are the only valid combinations):

```
176.51.71.24:15634

17.65.171.24:15634

17.65.17.124:15634

176.51.7.124:15634
```

But the [whois command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/whois) proved that I'm wrong.

I expected to get something like what mentioned in [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/353286/245156) answer.

Any idea?

Comment: Looks like a SteamID... are you on a real server or just a locally hosted game of a friend?

Comment: @dly I only play on the official dedicated servers and using the official matchmaking system.

Comment: I notice there's 4 groups in A:1:176517124:15634 (like an IPv4 address), but copious use of colons (as in IPv6). I can't shake the hunch that the server uses an IPv6 address, but maybe something in the console parser assumes IPv4 and ends up malforming it using regex or some other incorrect parsing/formatting. Like I said, just a hunch.

Comment: @sirreldar I have to mention that the characters in the third section is always just **numbers**,the first one is always **A** and the last one(right after the the closing brace) is **:0**.I don't think it's related to IPv6 at all.Does it print the address correctly in the Windows version for example?

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I'm not sure. I have windows version of CS:GO. After work tonight I will install it and take a look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That string is a SteamID for a [Steam Datagram Relay](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/multiplayer/steamdatagramrelay) enabled server. It is intended to hide the public IP address from players on the server, along with some other benefits, such as authentication, encryption, rate-limiting, protection from DOS attacks, and in some cases better ping.

Support for SDR was added to CSGO in 2016 according to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/580lxa/steam_datagram_relay_beta/) Reddit post by a Valve employee. Presumably, all CS:GO Public Matchmaking servers have migrated to SDR and do not expose the public IP address to players connected to it. In the same Reddit post, the author comments:

> You can tell that you are playing over SDR because the connect address will not be an IP address like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, it will look like “=[A:n:nnnnnnn]”

To answer your title question, the server IP address can be obtained on Linux (and Windows) using the "status" command, unless the server is using SDR, in which case the SteamID will be displayed instead of the IP address.

If the server is using SDR then you are unlikely to obtain the IP address using "white hat" methods, since one of the fundamental purposes of SDR is to keep the IP address secret from general knowledge.

Comment: Great! I actually wanted to get the IP addresses in order to add some servers in the file `Counter-Strike Global Offensive/csgo/cfg/server_blacklist.txt`(not because of blackhat purposes :) ).I wanted to blacklist them to eliminate the servers in some regions(because of the abundancy of the cheaters and toxics) like Dubai(persian players I mean.Not from UAE).I couldn't find any clue about what's the correct syntax is for that file and does it have any effect at all? Or is it for all the game modes?
All of these endeavors are just to prevent wasting my time when playing competitive matches.

Comment: I don't know. I would try putting the SDR SteamID in your blacklist file and seeing if it works. If not, then you should open a new question.